# Get names of first and last row for every run of 1

Tags: r

I have a data frame where:

```
df <- data.frame(position = c(1000,1156,3200,4629,5559,6100,7456,8208,9500,10000),
     col1 = c(1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0))
```

I want to create a separate table to get the values of first and last `position` for every run of 1. For example, the output for this data frame would be:

```
| first_position | last_position |
|  3200          |   5559        |
|  8208          |   9500        |
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using `dplyr`, `data.table::rleid`

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(key = rleid(col1)) %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  filter(col1 == 1, n() > 1) %>%
  summarize(first_position = first(position),
            last_position = last(position)) %>%
  select(-key)

  first_position last_position
           <dbl>         <dbl>
1           3200          5559
2           8208          9500
```